# Swift: array, textfields and UITableView

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to create an app that displays a table view based on an array of strings.

I have one view controller and a smaller content view within it. In the view controller there is a text field and a button that should save the written text in an array and display it in the table view controller. As well as embedding it in the content view.

I don't know how to save the written text and to add it in the array, perhaps using `append`.

How can I display the array in the table view and to save the array in NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your array in user defaults by code something like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arr, forKey: "myArray")
```

but remember, if you would to receive the array back you will have to cast AnyObject to [Int] in this example.

If you would save data in tableview, simply implement the DataSource protocol and when you put data to array in tableview then you can define how many rows your table should have by

```
func numberOfRowsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int
```

method (return array.count). The finally step is call reloadData() method. For more details see documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/numberOfRowsInSection:

**Edit:**
You need array of strings.

```
var strs = [String]()
strs.append(someTextField.text)
```

TextFields has property "text" that return text from textfield :-).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I didn't get something. How can I save the textfield's text in the array?

Comment: yes, thank you, later i'll try it and I'll tell you if I have problems

Comment: It doesn't work, because the text field and the array are in different view controller and I can't declare the textfield before the class.

Comment: So, you have to create object of ViewController that contains your tableview and pass the array by property :). Last step is perform pushViewController action :)